# JSON feed not working with android

Tags: php, android, json, rss, android-volley

i have this feed on this URL here ( [Feeds A](http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts) ) and this feeds here ( [Feeds B](http://encly.com/mobile/json/feed.json) )

when i insert **Feeds B** in android URL it works fine 100%

but when i insert **Feeds A** in android app URL it's not getting anything

here is my Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

    //Feeds URL - Your Website URL where you uploaded the admin panel
    private String URL_FEED = "http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts";
    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManagement session;
    Button btnLoadMore;

    ProgressDialog pDialog; 
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    // Flag for current page
    int current_page = 1;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Getting feeds from the website into listview 
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);


    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("fullName"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj.getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    ///Menus functions
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            session.logoutUser();
            break;
        case R.id.myProfile:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.addPhoto:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, UploadPhoto.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

i.stack.imgur.com/VtKhy.png

Feed A image not showing anything

i.stack.imgur.com/PT1Iz.png

Feed B image Showing all items correctly

**my Logcat**

```
    09-12 15:21:10.730: D/Volley(2426): [1] 1.onResponse: MainActivity
09-12 15:21:10.730: W/System.err(2426): org.json.JSONException: Value at 1 is null.
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:259)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.twaa9l.photosee.MainActivity.parseJsonFeed(MainActivity.java:151)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.twaa9l.photosee.MainActivity.access$7(MainActivity.java:146)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.twaa9l.photosee.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:121)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.twaa9l.photosee.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:1)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-12 15:21:10.734: W/System.err(2426):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

im using wordpress to get feeds for Feed A as this php code here

```
     <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query('showposts=3&post_type=usersposts'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  echo '{ "feed": [';
  $i = 1;
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
  $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
   $author_id=$post->post_author;
   $ProfilePicture = get_user_meta($author_id, '_cmb_profilePic');
   $gmt_timestamp = get_the_time( 'U', $post->ID ); 
   $username = get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', $author_id );
   $firstName = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $author_id );
   $lastName = get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $author_id );
  ?>

        {
            "id": <?php echo $i++; ?>,
            "name": "<?php echo $firstName." ".$lastName." - ".$username; ?>",
            "image": "<?php echo $featured_image; ?>",
            "status": "<?php echo the_title(); ?>",
            "profilePic": "<?php echo $ProfilePicture[0]; ?>",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },
  <?php

  endwhile;  
  echo ']}';

  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset

  function get_avatar_url($get_avatar){
    preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Do you see anything in your logcat that could help?

Comment: @hoomi updated with logcat

Comment: Your JSON is invalid; after `"url": null` you *always add a `},` -- it should only be `}` on the last item.

Comment: @323go i fix it and still same problem

Answer (score 1):

`http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts` does not appear to return a JSON object. Therefore your parseJSONFeed will probably not be working the way you want it to.

You need to define a URL that returns a JSON object (one that has file extension .JSON) `URL_FEED = "yourURLhere.json"` is JSON object that is acceptable for JsonObjectRequest to find a JSON object in Response.Listener().

In [the documentation](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html), it indicates that the JsonObjectRequest parameter "listener - Listener to receive the JSON response". But when you use `http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts`, it is not a JSON Object. It may LOOK like a JSON object, but it is not of type JSON object. Much like how a text file of type `.doc` LOOKS like a `.txt` file in Word, but it is NOT the same thing. `.doc` has different formatting embeded in it that you simply do not see.

Comment: im getting valuesfrom wordpress

Comment: @YoussefAlSubaihi, it doesn't matter where you get it if it's wrong.

Comment: i try to copy the working feed, replace it to the other not working one and i get same exception and its not working also

Comment: Are you saying you set `String URL_FEED = http://encly.com/mobile/json/feed.json";` and you still get the same exact error?
My interpretation of your log `org.json.JSONException: Value at 1 is null.` is that there is no value, because it is not a JSON object.

Comment: @erad no, when i copy the whole code from `http://encly.com/mobile/json/feed.json` to `http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts` i get `org.json.JSONException: Value at 1 is null.` BUT on the url `http://encly.com/mobile/json/feed.json` i get no errors and everything works correctly

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts` is not a JSON object in that it does not end in in ".json"
For example, when you create a text file in Word, its file extension is ".doc" (e.g. "mytxt.doc"). A basic text editor like notepad cannot read ".doc" files. It can, however, read files ending in ".txt" like "mytxt.txt". I think your issue is that JSONRequest only accepts urls ending in ".json"

Comment: @erad i changed it to `http://encly.com/mobile/json/feed.php` and it still working fine :( not naming problem !

Comment: i added this line of code to the page
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`
and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is not well formatted. You have one extra comma at the end of your JSON

Comment: i copy and past the json from feed b to feed A exactly as it is and still not working

Comment: Can you check if you get the same exception when you copy and paste the contents from FeedB

Comment: can you tell me what you see from this line `VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());`

Comment: this `09-12 15:15:28.034: D/Volley(2323): [1] 1.onResponse: MainActivity
`

Comment: I do not see the full log. can you paste it again

Comment: updated nothing changed with the logcat but i copy it all and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated above, your php produces invalid JSON.  You need to add the `,` only between items, not at the end. Something like the following should fix it:

```
echo '{ "feed": [';
$i = 1;

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
  if( $i > 1 ) 
     echo ','; 
  $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
   $author_id=$post->post_author;
   $ProfilePicture = get_user_meta($author_id, '_cmb_profilePic');
   $gmt_timestamp = get_the_time( 'U', $post->ID ); 
   $username = get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', $author_id );
   $firstName = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $author_id );
   $lastName = get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $author_id );
  ?>

        {
            "id": <?php echo $i++; ?>,
            "name": "<?php echo $firstName." ".$lastName." - ".$username; ?>",
            "image": "<?php echo $featured_image; ?>",
            "status": "<?php echo the_title(); ?>",
            "profilePic": "<?php echo $ProfilePicture[0]; ?>",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        }
  <?php

endwhile;  
echo ']}';
```

Note that I removed the comma from the end and only insert it at the beginning if it's not the first item.

Comment: Thank you for that, BUT on android side it still the same problem NOT GETTING ANY RESULTS :(

Comment: I don't think you've fixed it. I tested the [URL](http://apps.encly.com/?feed=all_posts) and it's still broken JSON.

Comment: i did, try to hit **ctrl+f5** on the browser to hard refresh or clear your browser cache

Comment: It's still returning broken json.

Comment: No. It's still invalid json. Go to the URL, copy it and paste it into jsoneditoronline.org. It's invalid... there's a comma that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was as [@erad said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25810888/4020063) the volly library didn't recognize the JSON data because it was look like JSON data but it's not

so i added this line of code to the page

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

and now it's working fine.